# Activate Numbers app and populate chart every 30 minutes

Tags: applescript, numbers

I'm editing this again to show the latest revision. Thanks to everyone's help here and some digging of my own, I've been able to get this to run in the background by avoiding the use of "system events"

Big thanks to everyone here, especially @Tetsujin for all the help!

My final step on this is to have it update 2 different tables in the same sheet. 1 at 10 minute intervals and 1 with 1 minute intervals. Will try my luck at it and post back if I get stuck.

````
set myTime to time of (current date) as string
set myAvg to 1.008

on roundThis(n, numDecimals)
    set x to 10 ^ numDecimals
    (((n * x) + 0.5) div 1) / x
end roundThis

repeat until myTime = 75600 -- stop at 9pm local time
    set myTime to (round ((time of date ((current date) as string)) / 60) rounding down) mod 10 = 0 --every 10 minutes
    if myTime then
        say "getting data"
        quit application "Numbers"
        delay 1
        
        tell application "Numbers" to open POSIX file "/Users/steve 1/Documents/document.numbers"
        delay 1
        
        --tell application "Numbers" to activate --only need this for testing
        
        tell application "Numbers"
            tell the table 1 of sheet 1 of document "document"
                set myAvg to the value of cell "C36"
            end tell
        end tell
        say roundThis(myAvg * 100, 2)
        
        tell application "Numbers"
            tell the table 1 of sheet 1 of document "document"
                add column before the range "E1:E2"
                set the value of cell "E1" to time string of (current date)
                repeat with i from 2 to the count of cells of column "E"
                    set the value of cell i of column "E" to (the value of cell i of column "C")
                end repeat
            end tell
        end tell
    end if
    delay 15 --less than 15 will cause it to get double triggered.
end repeat```
````

Comment: Can you put `display dialog time string of (current date) as text` right after 'set my time to…'. I'd like to see what string is actually being tested. Also, you have a couple of typos in your script. Your 'mycolumn' for AB actually shows 'Abraços, St'. And you have two '11:02:00 AM'. Finally, your 'numbers' section is really the best way to move data around. Getting the value of the source cells and then setting the target cells' values would be more reliable.

Comment: Long winded? Why not just do a check that the minutes is equal to 30? Or >30 <32?

Comment: Yes that would definitely cut out some lines but my goal is to make this adjustable so I can run it at any interval. Maybe there is a MOD function in AppleScript that I can use to find intervals like every 5 minutes or 10 minutes? Would that work?

Comment: Thanks Mockman. That was a quickkey that changed *AB*. Need to turn that off when I'm coding. You are saying my numbers system is the best way or did you mean NOT the best way?

Comment: Mockman is this what you are looking for?
"Thursday, August 12, 2021 at 6:59:48 PM"

Comment: You are getting the error because you are comparing an _integer_ against a _string_.  -- `set myTime to (time of date ((current date) as string))` returns an _integer_ , the value of which is the seconds since midnight, e.g. `33348`,  and **AppleScript** cannot convert the string, e.g., `"8:59:00 PM"` to an _integer_ in order to compare the two.

Answer (score 1):

This is a kind of half answer, just to be able to show the code properly.
You can eliminate all that redundancy with time comparisons using

```
set myTime to (time of date ((current date) as string))
if myTime & (round (myTime / 60) rounding down) mod 30 = 0 then
    --do function
end if
```

This will run the function if the time is :00 or :30 minutes. The rounding is because otherwise it would be triggered between :59.30 & :00.30 [& same on the half hour]

---

*After comments*
For some reason I cannot fathom, as written that does not return a boolean comparison. This version does [times shortened for patience reasons]…

```
repeat 60 times
    set myTime to (round ((time of date ((current date) as string)) / 60) rounding down) mod 5 = 0
    if myTime then
        display dialog "Triggered" buttons {"OK"}
    else
        display notification myTime
    end if
    delay 15
end repeat
```

Comment: I want to use myTime as the column header but not sure how to convert myTime to something like 8:30 PM

Comment: I thought this would work but also getting an error.

set myTimeNum to (time of date (current date))

Result:
error "Can’t get date (date \"Friday, August 13, 2021 at 8:14:19 AM\")." number -1728 from date (date "Friday, August 13, 2021 at 8:14:19 AM")

Comment: How would I set mod to work for 5 minute intervals instead of 30 minute intervals? mod 5 = 0?

Comment: `as string`, like in the example & yes, mod [any number of minutes] = 0 The number returned by that function is seconds since midnight.

Comment: Is it possible for this script to run in the background without pulling the window to the top? The reason it needs to come front now is because of the System Events call. Is there a way to copy and paste in the background?

Comment: No. You can only paste in the foreground.

Comment: It looks like I found a solution to run it in the background. Added modified code above. Now just have to figure out how to speak the value of a cell.

Comment: I changed mod 30 to mod 5 but it doesn't seem to execute at every 5th minute. For example at 7:05:00 it should execute right? I don't need to change anything else in your code example

Comment: Hi @Tetsujin this code to run every 30 minutes doesn't seem to work. Just in case I was doing something wrong, I used your code exactly as you have it so that it should run every 30 minutes and it didn't run on the hour or half hour. The latest version of the script is at the top of the page. Do I have something wrong? I see the many messages in the Replies tab at bottom of script window getting the current time and rounding it but it still never triggers the code within the if then statement.

Comment: Not sure why, but as written it doesn't return a true/false. I've tweaked into a working example that does - added to answer.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin ! Now it works perfect! Is there any problem to reduce the delay to 10? Is that just to save resources? I need it to execute as close to the minute as possible. Also will this work for 1 minute interval by setting mod 1=0 or is mod 5=0 the shortest possible interval? I tried with mod 1=0 but it was constantly triggered.

Comment: modulo is the remainder after integer division, so of course mod 1 will always return zero.

Comment: I'm new to applescript and noticed it has an export option for "script bundle" or "application". Would you recommend packaging in one of those ways? Would it be more efficient in some way? Right now I'm just running it from the script editor. I also saw in Automator that there is a Quick Action so that I would execute it from the Services menu. Not sure if there are any advantages to running them these different ways.

Comment: Sorry but you cannot keep on asking more & more questions in comments. This site doesn't work that way. It is not a chat or discussion forum. If you have a new question, please ask it as a new question.

Comment: Thank you and sorry about that. I'm learning as I go. :-)