# AppleScript conditional statement rules

Tags: applescript

I need a script to run between 9pm and 6am and I'm struggling to understand why this isn't working. I've tried with and without parentheses.

From the suggestions here, I removed "as string" but then got an error when I tried to run the app.

I figured out the error came from another line in the code that I didn't include in the example.

```
set myTimeB to (round ((time of date ((current date) as string)) / 60) rounding down) mod 5 = 0 --every 5 minutes
```

Any idea why this needs "as string" to function?

```
set myTime to time of (current date) --as string

if (myTime > 21600) and (myTime < 75600) then
    display notification "it's between 6am and 9pm"
else
    display notification "it's between 9pm and 6am"
end if
```

Comment: Your (edited) script works for me, but when comparing, the objects need to be of the same class.  Note that `current date` is a `date` object, with `time` being an integer of the number of seconds since midnight - see the [AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-BBCGECID).

Comment: Yes your answer worked user3439894 but I wasn't sure if I should delete and restart a new question. Still learning the ups and downs of this site.

Comment: @red_menace I don't know why it's working for you and not for me. Maybe what I wrote is not clear. The set myTimeB only works if I have it "as string" Without that, I get this error.
Can’t get time of date (date "Sunday, August 22, 2021 at 10:50:27 AM"). (-1728)

Comment: That must be from the other statement you mentioned.  It appears there is an issue when converting back and forth from a date, for example when you convert the date to a string, it is no longer a date object that has a time property.

Comment: Well the issue is only with myTimeB. It works as it is when declaring it as a string but I'm wondering why that is necessary. Since I'm dividing by 60 and then using mod it seems it should be declared as an integer.

Comment: All string/date conversion aside, if you are wanting to compare between 9PM of one day and 6AM of the _next_ day, you should be looking at the different `dates`, not just the `times`.

Comment: Actually the date doesn't matter. I just have some different things that need to happen if it's after 9pm and before 6am so that part is working. My only question now is why does this need to be declared a string. It seems integer would be more appropriate.
    set myTimeB to (round ((time of date ((current date) as string)) / 60) rounding down) mod 5 = 0 --every 5 minutes
Anyway I don't want to prolong the discussion here. It works as it is which is good enough for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update to address totally changed scope of original question:**

The issue as I see is that `of date` and `as string` in `((time of date ((current date) as string)) / 60)` do not belong there. It should just be:

```
set myTimeB to (round ((time of (current date)) / 60) rounding down) mod 5 = 0 --every 5 minutes`
```

- `(time of (current date)` returns an *integer*, so it's all set to be divided by `60`. There is no need to be coercing it to a *string*.
- `of date` makes no sense in the equation.

---

**Original answer:**

The following works for me:

```applescript
set myTime to time of (current date)

if (myTime > 21600) and (myTime < 75600) then
    display notification "it's between 6am and 9pm"
else
    display notification "it's between 9pm and 6am"
end if
```

Note that originally, `myTime` was a *string* and you were comparing it against an *integer*. Now it's being compared against the same *class*.

If you run the following in **Script Editor**:

```applescript
return class of time of (current date) & class of 21600
```

It returns: `{integer, integer}`

While the result of:

```applescript
set myTime to time of (current date) as string
return (class of myTime) & class of 21600
```

It returns: `{text, integer}`

Comment: Thanks. Actually my example is working now too. Very strange. Is it unreliable to test this as a string? It seems sometimes it works and sometimes it doens't.

Comment: @Steve Torrence, RE: "Is it unreliable to test this as a string?" --  From your own testing, yes as you have already found out. Comparing an _integer_ against another _integer_ as to one or the other _number_ being greater than or less than better not fail or the universe will start unraveling. 

Comment: This kind of puzzles me too - I'm by no means any kind of Applescript expert, but `set myTime to (time of date ((current date) as string))
return class of myTime & class of 21600` also gives `{integer, integer}` [from https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/425581/85275 ]

Comment: @Tetsujin - You’ve got some redundancy there.  The `current date` is getting coerced to a `string` and then converted back to a `date`.

Comment: It appears to be comparing them as strings, rather than integers. Essentially, it's comparing them alphabetically, so for example `"800" < 9` is true, because "8" comes before "9" in character sorting order (just like `"yaa" < "z" is true, because "y" comes before "z").

Comment: Yes integer is the way to go. I had it as string because of an earlier request for help that indicated this.
  set myTimeB to (round ((time of date ((current date) as string)) / 60) rounding down) mod 5 = 0 --every 5 minutes
I'm surprised I'm not having any trouble with that but I will change to integer also.

Comment: hmm when I change to Integer I get this error:
Can’t make date "Sunday, August 22, 2021 at 6:12:09 AM" into type integer. (-1700)

Comment: I edited the original example and noted where the code runs into the error. Not sure how to solve that.

Comment: Thanks @user3439894 ! That solved it. Sorry again for the confusion I caused in the discussion.